# iOS modularity: release app with 3rd party modules in it

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, plugins

We are building an app that provides some functionality ( let's call it F1). We need to make this functionality F1 available to other 3rd parties by means of an SDK providing an API that allows 3rd parties to create a new functionality (let's call it F2) and we want their software module to be integrated into the our App in the most modular way, like plug-ins.

So when the app starts up, it would check what modules are needed by the user( e.g. from the user settings) and would load only those ones.

What we want to achieve is:

1) load in memory an app with the smallest footprint possible ( not loading unused functionalities)

2) have a modular way to allow 3rd parties to develop their functionality as individual modules that we then integrate and distribute as a single app.

We are developing for iOS10 using swift 3

I know that there's a plugin architecture for cocoa but not for iOS.
Is there any way to achieve that in iOS? Any suggestion on any alternative approach.

Comment: https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html

Comment: AFAIK Cocoapods provides a mechanism to distribute code but I need other developers to plug their modules into my application ( not to just build a new app with use my library). Also I need a way to distribute binaries and NOT source code. Id don't know if with cocoapods this  is possible